# ffplay how to play interlaced yuv file

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv

I am playing an interlaced output yuv with ffmpeg and seeing the output is stuttering.

```
ffplay -v info -f rawvideo -pixel_format nv12 -video_size 720x480  data/yuvframes.yuv
```

Can anyone please let me know the exact syntax for playing it properly ?

Comment: Is your machine even capable of playing it in terms of performance? Does it work for non-interlaced video?

Comment: yes. if the yuv is for non-interlaced one, it plays fine. i'm able to view the yuv, but its as if corrupted.